# Scala Play: How to map JSON array structure to Case Class

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm completely new to Scala and Play and i stumbled upon the following the problem:

Given the following JSON structure:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Adam",
    "age": 19
  },
  {
    "name": "Berta",
    "age": 22
  },
...
]
```

I would like to map this JSON to a case classes like this:

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)
case class Users(users: Seq[User])
```

or at least something like `Seq[User]`.

I don't know how to traverse the JsPath because there is no key.

I tried to define an implicit read but either he cannot resolve the symbol "read" or he cannot found an implicit for user.

```
object User {
  implicit val reads: Reads[User] = Json.reads[User]
}
object Users {
  implicit val usersReads: Reads[Users] = (
    (JsPath).read[Seq[User]]
  )(Users.apply _)
}
```

How can I map my JSON to a working model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class User(name: String, age: Int)
case class Users(users: Seq[User])

object User {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[User]
}

object Users {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Users] = Reads {
      _.validate[Seq[User]].map(Users(_))
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but my IntelliJ told my that no implicits could be found  for Seq[User]..however could you shortly explain what the map part does? Thx!

Comment: You don't even need the second implicit object. `Json.parse(s).as[Seq[User]]` works just fine too.

Comment: its just ```.map(users => Users(users))```